# Не работает ссылка на фото "Invalid call at line require" react native TypeScript

Tags: typescript, url, react-native, require

У меня в json файле есть название карты
я вытаскиваю название карты и передаю значение в ссылку на фотографию, но выдает ошибку

```
Invalid call at line 49: require('../../../UI/Img/' + item.payment_system + '.png')

    <FlatList
    data={items}
    renderItem={({item}) =>
    <Image style={styles.pngphoto} source={require('../../../UI/Img/'+item.payment_system+'.png')} />/>
```

Путь до файла `'../../../UI/Img/Visa.png'`

`payment_system = Visa`